# Repeater OnItemDataBound, how to get the current row's data in codebehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

In my repeater, I want to set the content of a literal like:

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Literal id="lit" runat="server" />
</ItemTemplte>
```

I have my OnDataItemBound method in my code behind setup.

I've done this before, but only setting labels not actually getting the data for the current row that is being iterated on.

How do I get the data and the columns etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the `RepeaterItemEventArgs` in the OnDataItemBound method, you can access your data object through `e.Item.DataItem`:

```
void R1_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
    var obj = (MyObject)e.Item.DataItem;
    // use your object here to populate text boxes etc...
}
```